# Apply linear gradient on <hr>

Tags: css, gradient, linear-gradients

I want an hr that contains 50% of the page.

```
hr {
    background-color: #E0DFDF;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);

    border: none;
    margin: 1.5em auto;
    height: 1px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: What is `background-color: @border;`? Are you porting some code from preprocessor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `background-color: @border;` is invalid CSS. I guess you are porting some code from preprocessor (e.g. SASS), please fix it.
2. Your syntax is wrong:

   ```
   /* incorrect */
   -webkit-linear-gradient: (left, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
                          ^^
   /* correct */
   -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
   ```

Here's a demo:

```css
hr {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
  border: none;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  height: 1px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. `linear-gradient: (...)` should be ---> `linear-gradient(...)`, without the semi-colon(`:`).

```css
hr {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, #E0DFDF 50%, white 100%);
  border: 0;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  height: 1px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<hr />
```

Comment: @Harry - True! I forgot to mention that.